# ImportError on scandir

Tags: python-2.7, importerror, scandir

I am trying to use the [scandir package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/scandir/1.3) as an alternative to `os.walk` in python 2.7. However, during import an `ImportError` is raised as follows.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Jul  1 2016, 15:12:24) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> from scandir import scandir, walk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "scandir.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scandir import walk
ImportError: cannot import name walk
```

I haven't been able to find any references to this error (apart from circular imports) after searching extensively and quite stumped at this point. Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: Have you give this  a look ? https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir

Comment: @JamM.HernandezQ. I am trying to use the module you had mentioned. I installed it using `pip install scandir` inside a virtualenv. But I get the above errors after the package is installed !

Comment: I'm the author of the `scandir` package, and this is very strange. I tried pip installing it just now and that import statement works fine on both Python 3.5 and 2.7. What happens if you just do `import scandir`? And then what does it say when you type `scandir` (to show the module/source file)?

Answer (score 0):

You have a file called scandir.py in the current working directory.

rename it and let the scandir in sys.path do its magic.